# How do I remove a character at an index in c?

Tags: c, pointers

This is my program:
Does anyone know why it doesn't work?
My professor asked me to remove a character at an index using pointers, I'm also not allowed to use a for - loop so I'm kind of lost.

```
    int count = 0;
    int strl = strlen(s);
    char s2 [strl-1];

    if (index >= 0 && index < strl){
        while(count < strl){
            if (count == index){
                *(s+index) == *s;
                strl--;
            }
            count++;
        }
        printString(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: your `s` variable is not defined.

Comment: `*(s+index) == *s;` does nothing useful. It compares two values and discards the result.

Comment: If the new string has one less character, its size must be `strlen(s)` not `-1` as you  have it.

Comment: be aware yo have to shift ervery character behind idx one pos. to the left. So `if(count == index)` as the only condition for doing something can't be quite correct

Comment: Look at `memmove`

Comment: I suppose if `index >= 0` & `index < strl` shift all elements of array backward one at index to the end to 'fill' in that space, but you are left with an array +1 the size it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Your program won't work because your program don't modify strings.

You can use [`memmove()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) to shift the string after the character to be removed left by one character to remove a character. (Pointers are used as the arguments of `memmove()`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeAt(char* str, int idx) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    memmove(str + idx, str + idx + 1, len - idx);
}

int main(void) {
    char target[] = "0123456789";
    printf("before removing : %s\n", target);
    removeAt(target, 5);
    printf("after  removing : %s\n", target);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
before removing : 0123456789
after  removing : 012346789
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a character at index `i` from a string you need to move every character after it one space back:

```
void remove_at(char* s, size_t i) {
    if (!s) return;
    while (s[i]) {
        s[i] = s[i+1];
        i++;
    }
}
```

It's undefined behavior to pass an `i >= strlen(s)`, so beware.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using pointers to delete a character at a specific index in a string:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void DeleteChar(int index, char string[])
{
    char *ptr;

    assert(index >= 0);
    assert(index < strlen(string));
    
    ptr = string + index;
    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        *ptr = *(ptr + 1);
        ptr++;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "hello world";

    DeleteChar(9, string);
    puts(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, however, that it is safer and simpler to use only indices instead of pointers.